# How to reuse type names in C++ class definitions

Tags: c++, templates

For instance, suppose we have the following class,

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, and several others>
class Awesome_class<something non-trivial from T1, T2, ...> 
         : public Base_class<also something non-trivial from T1, ...> {
     ...class content...
}
```

and we need to use the type of the current class and its base classes in
the class body.  After searching and testing around for a while, I found that it seems that
the best way it can be done is to set aliases for them inside the class
definition, something like

```
using Current_class = Awesome_class<Repetition of the complicated things>;
using The_base_class = Base_class<Repetitions of the complicated things>;
```

This gives cleaner code than spelling everything out everywhere, but still I am
wondering if in *modern* C++ there are some cleaner ways to do this.
Specifically,

- Is there something like a magic usage of `decltype` or `auto` that just
  expands to the current class in the class body, including method bodies,
  prototypes, and class member declarations?
- Is there a good place to put a type alias for `Base_class<...>` such that
  this alias can be used both for the inheritance and inside the body of the
  class?

Sometimes, it feels that repeating the types even just twice seems to be a
real burden for maintenance.  Any suggestions are very deeply appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what "something non-trivial from T1, T2, ..." actually is. To just use e.g. `Awesome_class<T1, T2, and several others>` you can just use `Awesome_class` by itself. If you want something else, then you have no shortcuts.

Comment: You don't have to spell everything out. The template parameters of the current instance are implied in the class body.

Comment: If you want a complex alternative to `Awesome_class`, you can use `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>` within a member method. Anyway, note that `std::is_same_v<Awesome_class, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>>` is true. You don't actually need to specify the list if template parameters within a class to refer to the type of the class itself, it's name is enough.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For instance, it could be something like `<*T1, vector<T2>>`.  If simply `Awesome_class` could expand to whatever that is used for the partial specialization, then it immediately solves my first question.  I am going to give it a test now.  Thank you a lot!

Comment: @skypjack Yes this could given the type inside method bodies, but its usage in method prototypes or class member declarations might not be smooth.  Thank you anyway!

Comment: @DeiDei @JoachimPileborg Thank you so much, indeed just `Awesome_class` does the job!

Comment: @TschijnmoTschau Absolutely, that's why I suggested to use the class name and that's all. It was only to show a working alternative. ;-)